# Why doesn't this print the same list

Tags: python, arrays, function

```
new_list=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"] 

all_possible=[] #print of all possible combinations
y=0
z=0
def writer():
    for z in range(0, 26):
        all_possible.append(new_list[0] + "" + new_list[y] + "" + new_list[z])
    z = 0

def reader():
    for y in range(0, 26):
        writer()

reader()
print(all_possible)  
all_possible=[]



for y in range(0, 26):
    for z in range(0, 26):
        all_possible.append(new_list[0] + "" + new_list[y] + "" +new_list[z])
    z = 0
print(all_possible)
```

So I created this code to print a list that prints all the combinations of the alphabet with 3 characters and I also want to do that with a function but for some reason when I put the same thing in a function it doesn't print the same way for some reason. Can you help?

Comment: The y in the reader function is local. It does not modify the global y that writer is using.

Answer (score 0):

Your functions should accept parameters so that you can pass the list reference for the functions to modify:

```
new_list=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]

all_possible=[] #print of all possible combinations
def writer(l, y):
    for z in range(0, 26):
        l.append(new_list[0] + "" + new_list[y] + "" + new_list[z])

def reader(l):
    for y in range(0, 26):
        writer(l, y)

reader(all_possible)
print(all_possible)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want both the lists to give the same output, then you should add a parameter to the function writer. Otherwise value of y will always be zero and never change.

```
new_list=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"] 
all_possible1=[] #print of all possible combinations
y=0
z=0
def writer(y):
    for z in range(0, 26):
        all_possible1.append(new_list[0] + "" + new_list[y] + "" + new_list[z])
    z = 0

def reader():
    for y in range(0, 26):
        writer(y)

reader()
print(all_possible1)
all_possible2=[]



for y in range(0, 26):
    for z in range(0, 26):
        all_possible2.append(new_list[0] + "" + new_list[y] + "" +new_list[z])
    z = 0
print(all_possible2)
print(all_possible2 == all_possible1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it easily

```
import itertools
list(itertools.combinations(new_list, 3))
```

But according to the code you posted, I think you will want to do it your way, and learn more about syntax in python, so this answer is just a suggestion